# Download package to simplify complex conjugation

Tags: packages

I want to use `Needs` to download the `QuickReIm` package to simplify the complex conjugation, but I keep getting errors:

here is the Command:

```
Needs["QuickReIm`"]
```

and here are the errors:

> Get::noopen: Cannot open QuickReIm`.
>   Needs::nocont: Context QuickReIm` was not created when Needs was evaluated.

Do you know the reason? Where can I find different packages and their uses?

Comment: Is it in your Applications folder?

Comment: `Needs` does not download anything (please check its documentation). What it does is it loads a package, provided that that package is installed. Downloading the package and installing it is something you need to do yourself before the package can be used. "QuickReIm" is not a standard package. If you have a question about it, you should clarify where one can get this package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the package you're referring to, but after a quick search I found [*Quantum Methods with Mathematica*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tXIukmOFqscC&lpg=PA309&ots=74YB5kHTEy&dq=QuickReIm&pg=PA431#v=onepage&q=QuickReIm&f=false) (result 5) which gives the source code for their version of the QuickReIm package as

```
BeginPackage["QuickReIm`"]
Begin["`Private`"]
protected = Unprotect[Re, Im, Conjugate]
Conjugate[expr_] := expr /. Complex[x_, y_] :> x - I y
Re[expr_] := Expand[(expr + Conjugate[expr])/2]
Im[expr_] := Expand[(expr - Conjugate[expr])/(2 I)]
Protect[Release[protected]]
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

And then `` Needs["QuickReIm`"] `` evaluates without error.